# How to split Rails5 web and actioncable server [to make them run as a separate processes]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

Currently i have web and websocket servers running in the same process.
My question is how can i start web server without actioncable server but still be able to broadcast messages to clients of actioncable server in separate process?

In Rails5 beta to use action cable i was doing this `mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'` and simply removing this line i was able to achive exactly what i wanted.
But now it's mounted automaticaly...

I have tried '-C' commandline option with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For running the action cable as a separate process, we can follow section # 8 Running Standalone Cable Servers in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/action_cable_overview.html

**step1:** remove the below line from `config/routes.rb`

```
mount ActionCable.server => "/cable"
```

**step2:**
add the below line inside `config/application.rb`

```
config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
```

**step3:** make sure action cable url is set inside `config/environments/development.rb` and use port 3001 for action cable

```
config.action_cable.url = "ws://localhost:3001/cable"
```

**step4:** add `cable/config.ru` file with the following content

```
require ::File.expand_path('../../config/environment',  __FILE__)
Rails.application.eager_load!

run ActionCable.server
```

**step5:** Run the rails server in one terminal tab

```
rails s
```

**step6:** Run the action cable server in another terminal tab

```
bundle exec puma -p 3001 cable/config.ru
```

In this way you can run your rails server in 3000 port and action cable server in 3001 port